# What did Ripley tell Schenk in S01E06?

Tags: plot-explanation, luther

In the season finale of Season 1 of *Luther*, there's a pivotal scene near the end.  Previously, Ian Reed murdered Zoe Luther and framed John Luther for it.  Justin Ripley is under arrest after preventing the marksman from shooting Luther during his meeting with Reed at the Faraday Memorial.  The meeting was a ploy to get Reed away from his office so that Mark North could swipe the diamonds.  Reed has just discovered the theft and rushed off to intercept North.  Martin Schenk is beginning to notice that Reed is acting oddly. So he goes in to interrogate Ripley.

> SCHENK (to RIPLEY).  Something's happening that no one else can quite see.  Well, I want to see it!  What's happening?
>
> [RIPLEY starts to react.]
>
> [Cut away to REED on the chase.]
>
> [Cut back to SCHENK coming out of the interrogation room.]
>
> SCHENK (to CORNISH and TELLER).  We need to find Detective Chief Inspector Reed.  Most urgently.

Obviously, whatever Ripley said was enough to convince Schenk that Reed wasn't actually innocent.  But what could he have said?

As far as I can tell, Ripley doesn't really know anything that Schenk doesn't already know.  Ripley has had some private conversations with Luther, including the one where Luther told him "Don't trust Ian Reed".  But at this point, everyone knows that Luther is accusing Reed of the murder.  Ripley might actually believe it, but it's not clear that this is backed by anything except his loyalty to Luther.  And Ripley doesn't seem to have any knowledge of Reed's involvement in the robbery from the previous episode.  So what could he have told Schenk that would convince him?

Answer (score -1):

I haven't yet finished the first episode of season 2 so I could be wrong, but I don't think that Schenk was convinced at all. I just think he knew something was up and he wanted to get to the bottom of it. The easiest way to do that was to get Reed. There is a lot that happens between season 1 and season 2 that isn't explicitly explained. Schenk could still have suspected Luther of murdering his wife but was convinced by the recording of Reed's confession, the stolen diamonds, and Mark and Alice's witness accounts.